# Magento after upgradation from 1.4 to 2.2 facing Broken reference issue in system log

Tags: magento2.2.7

```
[2019-02-07 08:57:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-07 08:57:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-07 08:57:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-07 08:57:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions.gift_options' element cannot be added as child to 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-07 08:57:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'porto_header' respectively. [] []
[2019-02-07 08:57:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2019-02-07 08:57:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'upcoming-points-message-wrapper' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.search', but their parents are different: 'header-wrapper' and 'porto_header' respectively. [] []
[2019-02-07 08:57:11] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions.gift_options' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-02-07 08:57:11] main.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using an older or outdated version of porto for your shop. Make sure you have the Porto-Theme for Magento 2 installed like stated in the documentations:
https://www.portotheme.com/magento2/porto/documentation/